# Android Stackoverflow Error on Listview only on selected device

Tags: java, android, listview, view, stack-overflow

While **Developing Native App for Android** i gone through crash on a purticular **HTC DESIRE S** which is happening frequently purticularly on listview pages .

What the crash is on :

> 1. Listview  View overflow
> 2. Span overflow issue
> 3. Views Overflow issue
> 4. Other (Please explain )

Logcat:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:940)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.drawText(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1042)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Canvas.java:1323)
at android.text.Styled.drawUniformRun(Styled.java:141)
at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:298)
at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:357)
at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1797)
at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:679)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4338)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7014)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6739)
at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6512)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1499)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3194)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2607)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2054)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1632)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1335)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1991)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It would be great help to track this error because i tried lot of solution but it didn't work .

Comment: Could you post the `getView()` code?

Comment: Use Hierarchy View to examine your UI. My guess is that you have too many nested widgets.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes it is nested but i already optimised much but on purticular device i found this crash everytime . Please let me know further . I can't post code over here but can share with u by mail.

Comment: Can you post your list adapter?

Comment: Can you post not only the getView() code but the entire adapter?

Comment: I believe CommonsWare is spot on there. I had put unnecessary hierarchy in my layout, but when I flattened it (by using one `RelativeLayout`), the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 3):

As Commonsware said it seems you have too many nested views.

Try using more RelativeLayouts as they allow making complex views with less nesting. Also try refactor the whole screen, not only the list items.

If you want more help on how to do so, post your code.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 1):

This basically happens when you have too much views in your layout tree. 
Try to remove some view from your hierarchy, or go for this "dangerous" fix by overriding the draw() method of your ListView and add a try/catch:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
        super.draw(canvas);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO reschedule a redraw?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened with my samsung ace and didnt got any solution but luckily my freind found that the problem was typically  bcoz in  my code a program became infinitely recursive, but it can also occur in correctly written (but deeply recursive) programs.

So check your function having recursion in it.